# Is "throws ArithmeticException" only cosmetic in the method definiton?

Tags: java

I decided to remove the `throws ArithmeticException` in the code below and I still got the same result when I divided by zero and the stack trace appeared. Is `throws ArithmeticException` in the method definition optional? What is its purpose?

```
public static int quotient(int numerator, int denominator) throws ArithmeticException {
    return numerator / denominator;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        int denominator = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(quotient(10, denominator));
    } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("Aritmetic exception");
    } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("InputMismatchException");
    }
}
```

Comment: to gain a better understanding, search for "java checked exception".

Comment: `throws` does not prevent that a method throws. It means that this method might throw this exception, as a warning to its users. And if the excepion is a so called checked exception, then Java will force users of such a method to handle the exception. You might have had this already when using methods of the File API, IOException for example. But that particular exception is unchecked, so it is indeed purely cosmetic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ArithmeticException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException`, and unlike most exceptions, `RuntimeException`s are unchecked and so don't need to be declared in `throws` declarations. So yes, it's unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks so much. I saw it in a book which described the purpose of each line except that one. Now, it's clear.

Comment: @ZoltanKing To clarify: *"What is its purpose?"* **Documentation.** By specifying it in the `throws` clause, you're informing callers that the method might throw the exception. You should then also write javadoc for the method, where you can then document the conditions that would cause the exception to be thrown.